# Problem when inserting an url inside lstlisting and compiling with make4ht

Tags: listings, urls, make4ht

The following examples shows an error when an URL is inserted inside a `lstlisting` caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=tex, caption={Test (\url{http://www.test.org})}]
\LaTeX{}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The following error is found when compiling with `make4ht`:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    5    Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempa.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    5    Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempa.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    5    Undefined control sequence.
```

The log file shows the following message:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempa.
<to be read again>
                   1
l.5 ...caption={Test (\url{http://www.test.org})}]

You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\protect` and the option `tex4ht` will solve the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=tex, caption={Test (\protect\url{http://www.test.org})}]
\LaTeX{}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```